# Update a model in Mean Stack / Node / Mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mean-stack

Im having problem to update a model in my API. Im currently using a Mean Stack with "express": "^4.14.0" and "mongoose": "^4.7.2", with mongodb 3.2.11

When i try to PUT the changes to api, i receive the OK status, but the resource is not updated.

My controller looks like:

```
exports.getById = (req, res, next, id) => {
    Agent.findOne({
        _id: id
    }, (err, agent) => {
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (!agent) return next(new Error('Failed to load agent ' + id));
        req.agent = agent;
        next();
    });
};

exports.update = (req, res, next) => {
    var agent = req.agent;
    agent.save((err) => {
        if (err) return res.status(400).send({
            message: getErrorMessage(err)
        });
        res.json(agent);
    });
};
```

And my routes are:

```
app.route('/api/agents/:agentId')
    .get(agents.read)
    .put(agents.update)
    .delete(agents.delete);


app.param('agentId', agents.getById);
```

The big problem is with the PUT. Can anyone see the error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example update method:

```
Tweet.findById(tweetId, (err, tweet) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }

        tweet.message = editedTweetData.message;
        tweet.save(err => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });

        res.redirect('/');

    });
```